# Simplifying website testing

Tags: automated-tests

We are getting ready to start testing an enrollment webpage that has several pages and fields and we have generally used employees to do the testing.

The problem is, nobody tests for the same things.

I was wondering if there was a program that would run through the site and try to break it or is there no way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

WebDriver, Watir, Robot Framework, and other open source tools can help you with that.

I'd also recommend [Telerik's Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/), but I work for them so I'm biased about how great a tool it is.

Aside from tooling, Pavel's advice is a sound start. If you're looking to automate your tests then you also have to understand that carefully choosing what to automate is **critical**. Don't waste time on automating look and feel tests, focus on the high value/high risk areas of your system.

You'll also need to allow yourself some potentially significant ramp up time to learn how to do automation well in your particular environment. UI automation is a difficult problem domain, so you've got to dive into it with proper expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is bit general, there are some advices:

- Common advice is to **first write down your tests**. If every employee tests differently, it means that you have no *test scenario* present. This step should be in human language, with steps and expected result. This will get you idea, what you actually need.
- After writing down the tests, think about **test data** or even **test environment** - what data (user accounts, user roles, input files, output files...) are you going to need.
- Then think about **automated testing**. My personal favorite is [Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted). Its not the only possibility and maybe even not the best one for you, because everyone has different needs.